How to apply cld() on specific groups of lsmeans() output?
I have a pretty large model (MLM_LAI_10_DIC), with more than 7000 values. When I use cld() on lsmeans() on my model, I get too many groups. Is there any way to apply cld() on just some of the values? Like making a filter.
> cld_ecosistema<-cld(lsmeans(MLM_LAI_10_DIC,~Severidad.x*num.mes|ecosistema_b))
> cld_ecosistema
ecosistema_b = bosque:
 Severidad.x    num.mes lsmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL .group                    
 Severidad alta 61       0.239 0.0707 159  0.09941    0.379  1234                     
 Severidad alta 37       0.266 0.0729 178  0.12246    0.410  12345678                 
 Severidad baja 61       0.286 0.0729 178  0.14212    0.430  12  56  90A              
 Severidad alta 73       0.286 0.0707 159  0.14673    0.426  12345678 0 B             
 Severidad baja 37       0.293 0.0729 178  0.14878    0.436  12  56  90A              
 Severidad baja 73       0.294 0.0707 159  0.15447    0.434  12  56  90A              
 No quemado     61       0.310 0.0717 168  0.16803    0.451  1 3 5 7 9   C            
 No quemado     37       0.340 0.0717 168  0.19808    0.481  1 3 5 7 9   C            
 No quemado     73       0.344 0.0707 159  0.20401    0.483  1 3 5 7 9   C            
 Severidad alta 1        0.386 0.0989 467  0.19161    0.580  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad alta 13       0.412 0.0707 159  0.27261    0.552      567890ABCD           
 Severidad baja 1        0.442 0.0743 192  0.29498    0.588  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad baja 49       0.451 0.0707 159  0.31107    0.590  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad alta 49       0.458 0.0707 159  0.31855    0.598          9 A CD           
 Severidad alta 25       0.474 0.0707 159  0.33461    0.614          9 A CD           
 Severidad baja 13       0.484 0.0707 159  0.34451    0.624    34  78   BCD           
 Severidad baja 25       0.489 0.0717 168  0.34692    0.630    34  78   BCD           
 Severidad baja 85       0.513 0.0707 159  0.37283    0.652    34  78   BCD           
 Severidad alta 85       0.519 0.0707 159  0.37966    0.659          9 A CD           
 No quemado     49       0.529 0.0707 159  0.38922    0.669   2 4 6 8 0AB D           
 No quemado     25       0.624 0.0707 159  0.48404    0.763       6 8 0AB D           
 No quemado     13       0.640 0.0707 159  0.50076    0.780       6 8 0AB D           
 No quemado     85       0.647 0.0707 159  0.50754    0.787           0AB D           
 No quemado     1        0.650 0.0717 168  0.50834    0.792           0AB D           

ecosistema_b = higrofilo:
 Severidad.x    num.mes lsmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL .group                    
 Severidad baja 73       0.281 0.0707 159  0.14177    0.421  1234                     
 Severidad alta 61       0.288 0.0707 159  0.14796    0.427  1   5                    
 Severidad alta 73       0.294 0.0707 159  0.15465    0.434  1   5                    
 Severidad baja 61       0.302 0.0717 167  0.16022    0.443  1234                     
 Severidad alta 37       0.356 0.0707 159  0.21655    0.496  12  567890A              
 Severidad alta 13       0.432 0.0707 159  0.29222    0.572  123 567890ABCDEFG        
 Severidad baja 37       0.448 0.0707 159  0.30864    0.588  1234567    BC    HI      
 No quemado     73       0.464 0.0707 159  0.32472    0.604  123456 89  B DE  H JK    
 Severidad alta 1        0.465 0.0787 236  0.31013    0.620  1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLM  
 Severidad baja 49       0.508 0.0707 159  0.36815    0.648      5678 0 BCD F HIJ L   
 Severidad alta 49       0.517 0.0707 159  0.37754    0.657   234 67890ABCDEFGHIJKLM  
 Severidad baja 85       0.556 0.0707 159  0.41630    0.696      567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMN 
 No quemado     61       0.562 0.0717 167  0.42034    0.703  1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLM  
 Severidad alta 25       0.566 0.0707 159  0.42588    0.705    34       BCDEFGHIJKLMN 
 Severidad alta 85       0.648 0.0707 159  0.50806    0.787     4             HIJKLMN 
 Severidad baja 25       0.668 0.0707 159  0.52877    0.808         890A  DEFG  JKLMN 
 No quemado     37       0.681 0.0707 159  0.54096    0.820        7  0A C  FG I  LM  
 Severidad baja 13       0.691 0.0707 159  0.55082    0.830          9 A   E G   K MN 
 No quemado     49       0.698 0.0707 159  0.55810    0.838        7  0A C  FG I  LM  
 Severidad baja 1        0.702 0.0717 167  0.56053    0.844          9 A   E G   K MN 
 No quemado     85       0.924 0.0707 159  0.78471    1.064                         N 
 No quemado     25       1.109 0.0707 159  0.96957    1.249                          O
 No quemado     13       1.132 0.0707 159  0.99240    1.272                          O
 No quemado     1        1.150 0.0707 159  1.00979    1.289                          O

ecosistema_b = matorral:
 Severidad.x    num.mes lsmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL .group                    
 Severidad baja 61       0.166 0.0830 281  0.00288    0.330  1234567890AB             
 Severidad baja 37       0.181 0.0766 213  0.02963    0.332  1234567890AB             
 No quemado     37       0.208 0.0717 167  0.06668    0.350  1 3  6                   
 Severidad baja 73       0.235 0.0707 159  0.09487    0.374  1234567890AB             
 No quemado     61       0.237 0.0728 178  0.09318    0.381  1234 67                  
 Severidad alta 73       0.243 0.0707 159  0.10367    0.383  12  5   9                
 Severidad alta 61       0.266 0.0717 168  0.12405    0.407  12345  890               
 Severidad baja 25       0.276 0.0746 194  0.12891    0.423  1234567890AB             
 No quemado     73       0.279 0.0707 159  0.13933    0.419  12345678  A              
 Severidad baja 1        0.280 0.0792 240  0.12381    0.436  1234567890AB             
 Severidad alta 37       0.287 0.0744 192  0.14064    0.434  12345  890               
 Severidad baja 85       0.323 0.0731 180  0.17827    0.467  1234567890AB             
 No quemado     49       0.344 0.0707 159  0.20456    0.484  1234567890AB             
 Severidad baja 49       0.350 0.0707 159  0.21066    0.490  1234567890AB             
 Severidad baja 13       0.363 0.0719 169  0.22147    0.505  1234567890AB             
 No quemado     1        0.386 0.0707 159  0.24666    0.526   2 45 7890AB             
 No quemado     25       0.417 0.0707 159  0.27763    0.557      5  890AB             
 Severidad alta 13       0.437 0.0707 159  0.29685    0.576    34 678 0AB             
 No quemado     13       0.442 0.0707 159  0.30221    0.582      5  890AB             
 Severidad alta 49       0.484 0.0707 159  0.34456    0.624       67   AB             
 No quemado     85       0.488 0.0717 168  0.34599    0.629          90 B             
 Severidad alta 25       0.491 0.0707 159  0.35145    0.631       67   AB             
 Severidad alta 85       0.560 0.0707 159  0.42014    0.700       67   AB             
 Severidad alta 1       nonEst     NA  NA       NA       NA                           

ecosistema_b = xerofito:
 Severidad.x    num.mes lsmean     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL .group                    
 Severidad baja 61       0.157 0.0717 168  0.01520    0.298  123                      
 Severidad baja 73       0.169 0.0707 159  0.02927    0.309  123456                   
 Severidad baja 37       0.184 0.0707 159  0.04401    0.323  123456                   
 No quemado     61       0.218 0.0707 159  0.07837    0.358  123   789                
 No quemado     37       0.223 0.0707 159  0.08319    0.363  123   789                
 Severidad alta 73       0.225 0.0707 159  0.08493    0.364  1  4  7  0               
 No quemado     73       0.235 0.0707 159  0.09571    0.375  123   789                
 Severidad baja 13       0.250 0.0707 159  0.11038    0.390  1234567890AB             
 Severidad alta 61       0.259 0.0707 159  0.11939    0.399  12 45 78 0A              
 Severidad baja 1        0.280 0.0762 210  0.13011    0.430  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad baja 25       0.286 0.0717 167  0.14426    0.427  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad baja 49       0.295 0.0707 159  0.15558    0.435  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad alta 37       0.306 0.0707 159  0.16610    0.446  12 45 78 0A              
 No quemado     1        0.329 0.0707 159  0.18974    0.469  123   789   C            
 Severidad baja 85       0.358 0.0707 159  0.21801    0.497        7890ABCD           
 No quemado     25       0.360 0.0707 159  0.22026    0.500  123   789   C            
 No quemado     49       0.365 0.0707 159  0.22532    0.505  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad alta 13       0.366 0.0707 159  0.22579    0.505  1234567890AB             
 No quemado     13       0.375 0.0707 159  0.23519    0.515  1234567890ABCD           
 Severidad alta 49       0.425 0.0707 159  0.28540    0.565   23 56 89 AB             
 Severidad alta 25       0.512 0.0707 159  0.37239    0.652    3  6  9  BCD           
 No quemado     85       0.529 0.0707 159  0.38887    0.668     456   0AB D           
 Severidad alta 85       0.618 0.0707 159  0.47877    0.758              CD           
 Severidad alta 1       nonEst     NA  NA       NA       NA                           

(1) It is possible to specify cld() such that it returns the difference between "num.mes=1" and "num.mes=85"? (2) And get letters just between those two "num.mes" values?
